# How do i fix my JSON format by using php

Tags: php

I try to send json format to my android app , but i find that my json format is uncorrect.

```
{data={"image":"http:\/\/www.androidhive.info\/wp-content\/uploads\/2016\/01\/Air-1.png","message":{"chat_room_id":"","created_at":"2017-03-22 3:34:30","message_id":"","message":"77"},"user":{"user_id":null,"gcm_registration_id":null,"name":null,"created_at":null,"email":null}}, flag=0, title=Google Cloud Messaging, is_background=false}
```

I set the data like this:
`$app->post('/users/send_to_all'`,

```
 function() use ($app) {

    $response = array();
    verifyRequiredParams(array('user_id', 'message'));

    require_once __DIR__ . '/../libs/gcm/gcm.php';
    require_once __DIR__ . '/../libs/gcm/push.php';

    $db = new DbHandler();

    $user_id = $app->request->post('user_id');
    $message = $app->request->post('message');


    require_once __DIR__ . '/../libs/gcm/gcm.php';
    require_once __DIR__ . '/../libs/gcm/push.php';
    $gcm = new GCM();
    $push = new Push();

    //get the user using userid
    $user = $db->getUser($user_id);

    //creating tmp message , skipping database insertion
    $msg = array();
    $msg['message'] = $message;
    $msg['message_id'] = '';
    $msg['chat_room_id'] = '';
    $msg['created_at'] = date('Y-m-d G:i:s');

    $data = array();
    $data['user'] = $user;
    $data['message'] = $msg;
    $data['image'] = 'http://www.androidhive.info/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/Air-1.png';


    $push->setTitle("Google Cloud Messaging");
    $push->setIsBackground(FALSE);
    $push->setFlag(PUSH_FLAG_USER);
    $push->setData($data);

    //sending message to topic `global`
    //on the device every user should subscribe to `global` topic
    $gcm->sendToTopic('global', $push->getPush());

    $response['user'] = $user;
    $response['error'] = false;

    echoRespnse(200, $response);
});
```

Here is my `Push.php` about `getPush()`:

```
public function getPush() {
        $res = array();
        $res['title'] = $this->title;
        $res['is_background'] = $this->is_background;
        $res['flag'] = $this->flag;
        $res['data'] = $this->data;

        return $res;
    }
```

Here is my `Gcm.php` about `sendToTopic`:

```
//sending message to a topic by topic id
    public function sendToTopic($to, $message) {
        $fields = array(
            'to' => '/topics/' . $to,
            'data' => $message,
        );
        return $this->sendPushNotification($fields);
    }
```

I'm really not familiar with php , how do i fix the JSON format ?

Any help would be appreciated , thanks in advance !

I update my question , i find json_encode in my Gcm.php:

It's on `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));`

```
class GCM {

    //constructor
    function __construct() {

    }

    //sending push message to single user by gcm registration id   (array 最後面有， 待看)
    public function send($to, $message) {
        $fields = array(
            'to' => $to,
            'data' => $message,
        );
        return $this->sendPushNotification($fields);
    }

    //sending message to a topic by topic id
    public function sendToTopic($to, $message) {
        $fields = array(
            'to' => '/topics/' . $to,
            'data' => $message,
        );
        return $this->sendPushNotification($fields);
    }

    //sending push message to multiple users by gcm registration ids
    public function sendMultiple($registration_ids, $message) {
        $fields = array(
            'registration_ids' => $registration_ids,
            'data' => $message,
        );
        return $this->sendPushNotification($fields);
    }

    //function makes curl request to gcm servers  (__DIR__  待看)
    private function sendPushNotification($fields) {
        //include config
        include_once __DIR__ . '/../../include/config.php';

        //Set POST variable
        //$url = 'https://gcm-http.googleapis.com/gcm/send';
        $url='https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';

        $headers = array(
            'Authorization: key=' . GOOGLE_API_KEY,
            'Content-Type: application/json'
        );
        //open connection
        $ch = curl_init();

        //set the url , number of POST vars , POST data
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

        //Disabling SSL Certificate support temporarly
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));

        //Execute post   (=有三個?)
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        if ($result === FALSE){
            die('Curl failed: '. curl_error($ch));
        }
        //close connection
        curl_close($ch);

        return $result;
    }

}

?>
```

It's still let my json format incorrect , how do i fix ?

Comment: just use json_encode($response);

Comment: Where should i use this code ?  Is function `getPush() about return json_encode($res)`  ?

Comment: I had tried `return json_encode($res);` on `getPush()`  , it cause me can't send json information to my app.

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON is invalid. try:

```
{"data":{"image":"http:\/\/www.androidhive.info\/wp-content\/uploads\/2016\/01\/Air-1.png","message":{"chat_room_id":"","created_at":"2017-03-22 3:34:30","message_id":"","message":"77"},"user":{"user_id":null,"gcm_registration_id":null,"name":null,"created_at":null,"email":null}}, "flag":0, "title":"Google Cloud Messaging", "is_background":false}
```

Notice ive replaced usage of `=` with `:` and wrapped keys and strings in quotes `(")`

To get it into a nice json string with php you need to build your array correctly first. Possible way is to setup a response array and then you can `json_encode()` it.

```
    $response =[
    'data' => $data,
    'flag' => 0,
    'title' => 'Google Cloud Messaging',
    'is_background' => false.       
    ];
```

now you can

```
json_encode($response);
```

Comment: thanks for your answer , but i don't know how to send the correct json format by php in my case.

Comment: You just need to build your php array correctly first. Please see if my update in my answer is helpful.

Comment: thanks man , but i try your code instead of `getPush()` , it become that can't be send the message to my app

Answer (score 1):

PHP has some built-in json functions, you need json_encode() and json_decode().

For example this code:

```
<?php 
$arr = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3, 'd' => 4, 'e' => 5);
echo json_encode($arr);
?>
```

Will print:

```
{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}
```

Here's the [link to documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) for json_encode() and for the entire [json in php documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/book.json.php).

Hope this helps.